# Does an orthonormal basis on $\Lambda^2 V$ induces an orthonormal basis on $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, tensors

Suppose $(V, \langle.,.\rangle)$ is a $n$-dimensional inner product vector space and $\Lambda^2 V$ the set of all bivectors with induced inner product.

> Does an orthonormal basis for $\Lambda^2 V$ induces an <del>(unique)</del> orthonormal basis on $V$?

Obviously the converse is true.  By supposing $\{X_1, \dots,X_\ell\}$ is an orthonormal basis ($\ell=n(n-1)/2$) for $\Lambda^2 V$. Then I think  one can find (but how explicitly) the set of all $E_i$ such that $X_k=\text{span}\{E_i,E_j\}$ for appropriate $k,i,j$. Then I think these $E_i$ (by not considering iterated elements) are orthonormal and if are not then one can apply Gram–Schmidt process. but I doubt. <del>And is this unique?</del>

Also I know that $\Lambda^2 V\simeq \mathfrak{so}(n)$ if it helps.

Comment: Well, the orthonormal bases of $\Lambda^2V$ are in (noncanonical) bijection with $O(d)$, where $d=\binom{n}{2}$. For $n>3$, we have $d>n$, so the space of orthonormal bases of $\Lambda^2V$ is higher-dimensional than the same space for $V$. That means there shouldn't be any "natural" way to produce a unique basis of $V$ from one of $\Lambda^2V$. If you ignore uniqueness, you're essentially looking for an $O(n)$-equivariant map $O(d)\to O(n)$. (Feel free to replace $O$ with $SO$ if you want to get orientation involved.)

Comment: $O(d)$ or $O(q)$ with $q= {n\choose d}$?

Comment: Look at $n=2$: a (n orthonormal) basis in $\Lambda^2V$ amounts to a choice of a unit area element, there is no way to consistently pick a basis in $V$ from that. If there would be, then any rank 2 vector bundle with trivial exterior square would be trivial.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: for  $n=2$ we know that bivectors are decomposable so I think one can find such basis. isn't?

Comment: No. For instance consider $\{e_1\wedge e_2\}$ as a basis for $\Lambda^2\Bbb R^2$. What basis of $\Bbb R^2$ do you think that gives? Don't say $\{e_1,e_2\}$, though, because $ e_1\wedge e_2=v_1\wedge v_2 $ where $v_1=(e_1+e_2)/\sqrt{2}$ and $v_2=(e_2-e_1)/\sqrt{2}$, so the element $e_1\wedge e_2$ can't tell the difference between $\{e_1,e_2\}$ and $\{v_1,v_2\}$.

Comment: @runway44: as you write in first comment I want to ignore the uniqueness.

Comment: @runway44: what do you meant by O(n)-equivariant map?

Comment: $O(n)$ acts on $O(\Lambda^2\Bbb R^n)$, in order to be "natural" the map $O(\Lambda^2\Bbb R^n)\to O(n)$ needs to respect this action. (Feel free to put "equivariant map" into a search engine.) This notion of naturality is what originally motivated the definition of functors.

Comment: For a specific example: let $V$ be the subspace of $W:=\mathbb R\left\langle e_1,e_2,e_3\right\rangle$ consisting of those $\lambda_1e_1+\lambda_2e_2+\lambda_3e_3$ with $\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3=0$. Then $\Lambda^2V$ is the 1-dimensional subspace of $\Lambda^2W$ spanned either by $\omega:=e_1\wedge e_2+e_2\wedge e_3+e_3\wedge e_1$ or by its negative. Now suppose you choose a basis here, i. e. pick any nonzero scalar multiple of $\omega$. How does this give you a basis in $V$?

Comment: It's also important to note that bivectors are generally not decomposable so you can't write $X_k = E_i \wedge E_j$ (which is what I guess you mean by $X_k = "\operatorname{span}" (E_i, E_j))$.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: I think one can rewrite $\omega$ as $(e_1-e_2)\wedge (e_2-e_3)$. So $(e_1-e_2)/\sqrt{2}$ and $(e_2-e_3)/\sqrt{2}$ is a basis for $V$.

Comment: The same is true for $(e_2-e_3)\wedge(e_3-e_1)$ and $(e_3-e_1)\wedge(e_1-e_2)$.

Comment: And to illustrate also what @levap says, here is another, similar example: take $V$ the subspace of $W:=\mathbb R\left\langle e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4\right\rangle$ of those $\sum_i\lambda_ie_i$ with $\sum_i\lambda_i=0$. Then $\Lambda^2V$ is the 3-dimensional subspace of $\Lambda^2W$ spanned by those $\sum_{i<j}\lambda_{ij}e_i\wedge e_j$ satisfying$$\lambda_{12}+\lambda_{13}+\lambda_{14}=\lambda_{12}-\lambda_{23}+\lambda_{24}=\lambda_{13}+\lambda_{23}-\lambda_{34}=0.$$

Comment: One basis here is given by, say,\begin{align*}&e_1\wedge e_2-e_1\wedge e_4-e_2\wedge e_4,\\&e_1\wedge e_3-e_1\wedge e_4+e_3\wedge e_4,\\&e_2\wedge e_3+e_2\wedge e_4+e_3\wedge e_4.\end{align*}What do you do with this one?

Comment: OK, This was my try that seems is not applicable. Is there another way to construct a basis if $n>3$?

Comment: It becomes worse with larger $n$, I believe.

Comment: Also there is a trivial case $n=1$: here choice of a basis in $\Lambda^2V$ amounts to doing nothing, while to choose a basis in $V$ you have to do something (pick a nonzero element in $V$).